# Rails form_tag not submitting if nothing changed

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, post

I've got a problem with form_tag in rails (4.0.2). This form below is *sometimes* not submitting (problem: submit-button is not responding). If you reload the complete page, the form and submit button is working.

```
    <table>
        <%= form_tag update_students_courses_path(@student.id) do %>

          <% @all_courses.each do |c|%>
          <tr>  
            <td><%= c.name %></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag  'checks[]', c.id, @courses.include?(c)  %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>     

        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
        <%= submit_tag "update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    <%end %>
```

The form is inside a (bootstrap) modal div, but I think this causes no problem. I also tried to disable the caching with a befor filter, but there are not positive effects. (maybe the way I disabled wasn't correct?)

```
      before_filter :set_no_cache, only: [:show, :updateCourses]

  def set_no_cache
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
```

Thanks to all your replies!

Comment: Are you use turbolinks gem?

Comment: yes, i do use turbolinks

Comment: I found the solution myself:

the Inside of the bootstrap modal div is hidden whend you load the page. When you put         

    <%= form_tag update_students_courses_path(@student.id) do %>

to the outside of the hidden area, the form will not be disabled, when the page is loaded. I think this has caused the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/280 see this issue, may be it's help you